# how to organize the result of x and y coordinates as an ASCII X-Y plot?

Tags: c++, math, bitmap, trigonometry, gedit

I am doing a former assignment in C++ and trying to figure out how to get correct ASCII X-Y plot.

So what's really happening is that user is given a menu which allows them to choose a particular trig function.All of the functions have range between [-4..6] for X and [-12...5] for Y.Next user will be allowed to select amount of graduations(or values between the restricted x and y range] and if they want to see resultant values or Bitmap.The final output will be in values/bitmap.I have pasted wolfram alpha link for the functions in comments.

What I have done is incremented each column in 2D output by product of  1/(graduation-1)(i.e. 1/3 if graduated value is 4) and column #.Once that product reaches 1,I am not getting correct [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQclL.png) for the values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;


double minX=-4;
double maxX=6;
double minY=-12;
double maxY=5;



 void displayValues(double result[],int result_size,int graduationVal,double percentIncrease,int menuSelection){

     int displaySelection=0;
     cerr<<"(0) Bitmap or (1) Values?";
     cin>>displaySelection;
     int k=0;
     int i=0;
     int division=0;

     //Add Values into array until result-1 values
     while(i < result_size){
       //cout<<"Before j";
       //Calculate all the horizontal axis values
for(int j=0; j< graduationVal;j++){

        if(displaySelection==1){

            //cout<<"In if";
            if(menuSelection==1){
                result[i]=sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j))*cos(minY+(percentIncrease*k));
                cout<<"\n Increase in value of x by "<<percentIncrease*j<<" ";
                cout<<"Increase in value of y by "<<percentIncrease*k<<"\n";
                //cout<<sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j))<<"\n";
                //cout<<cos(minY+(percentIncrease*k))<<"\n";
                cout<<result[i]<<" ";
            }else if(menuSelection==2){
                result[i]=sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j))+pow(cos(minY+(percentIncrease*j)),2)-(minX+(percentIncrease*j))/(minY+(percentIncrease*k));
                cout<<"\n Increase in value of x by "<<percentIncrease*j<<" ";
                cout<<"Increase in value of y by "<<percentIncrease*k<<"\n";

                cout<<result[i]<<" ";

            }else if(menuSelection==3){

                result[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j)))+(0.5 *cos(minY+(percentIncrease*k)));
                cout<<"\n Increase in value of x by "<<percentIncrease*j<<" ";
                cout<<"Increase in value of y by "<<percentIncrease*k<<"\n";

                cout<<result[i]<<" ";


            }else if(menuSelection==4){

                result[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j)))+(minX+(percentIncrease*j)) * cos(3 * (minY+(percentIncrease*k)));   
                cout<<result[i]<<" ";

            }

            //cout<<"J is"<<j<<"\n";
            //cout<<"K is"<<k<<"\n";
            //cout<<"I is"<<i<<"\n";
        }else{

            if(menuSelection==1){
                result[i]=sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j))*cos(minY+(percentIncrease*k));
                cout<<((result[i] > 0 )?"O":"X");

            }else if(menuSelection==2){

                result[i]=sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j))+pow(cos(minY+(percentIncrease*j)),2)-(minX+(percentIncrease*j))/(minY+(percentIncrease*k));
                cout<<((result[i] > 0 )?"O":"X");

            }else if(menuSelection==3){

                result[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j)))+(0.5 *cos(minY+(percentIncrease*k)));
                cout<<((result[i] > 0 )?"O":"X");


            }else if(menuSelection==4){

                result[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(percentIncrease*j)))+(minX+(percentIncrease*j)) * cos(3 * (minY+(percentIncrease*k)));       
                cout<<((result[i] > 0 )?"O":"X");

               }


        }//End display choice if


        //Increment Array Index
        i++;
        //cout<<"Bottom of j";
    }//End of j loop

cout<<"\n";

//Increment y-values
if(k<graduationVal){

    k++;
   }

  }//End of While

}


int main(){

    int menuChoice=-1;
    int displaychoice=0;

    double distanceFromMinMaxX=4+6;
    double distanceFromMinMaxY=12+5;

    int graduations=0;

    // double precisionX;
    // double precisionY;

    double pctIncrease;

    while(menuChoice!=0){

      cerr<<"Select your function\n";
      cerr<<"1. sin(x)cos(y)\n";
      cerr<<"2. sin(x)+cos^2(x)-x/y\n";
      cerr<<"3. 1/2 sin(x) + 1/2 cos(y)\n";
      cerr<<"4. 1/2 sin(x) + xcos(3y)\n";
      cerr<<"0. Quit\n";
      cin>>menuChoice;

      if(menuChoice == 0){

        return 0;
      }

      cerr<<"Number of graduations per axis: ";
      cin>>graduations;

      pctIncrease=1/(double)(graduations - 1);
      int values_size=graduations * graduations;

      double values[values_size];


      /*int yValues[graduationVal];*/

     // precisionX=distanceFromMinMaxX/graduations;
     // precisionY=distanceFromMinMaxY/graduations;


      displayValues(values,values_size,graduations,pctIncrease,menuChoice);


    }

 }
```

Edit:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    double minX=-4;
    double maxX=6;
    double minY=-12;
    double maxY=5;


double* calculateValues(double val[],int val_size,int graduationVal,double xPrecision,double yPrecision,int menuSelection){

  /*int displaySelection=0;
  cerr<<"(0) Bitmap or (1) Values?";
  cin>>displaySelection;*/

  int k=0;
  int i=0;

  //Add Values into array until result-1 values
  while(i < val_size){
    for(int j=0; j<graduationVal;j++){
                if(menuSelection==1){
                    val[i]=sin(minX+(xPrecision*j))*cos(minY+(yPrecision*k));

                }else if(menuSelection==2){
                    val[i]=sin(minX+(xPrecision*j))+pow(cos(minY+(xPrecision*j)),2)-(minX+(xPrecision*j))/(minY+(yPrecision*k));

                }else if(menuSelection==3){

                    val[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(xPrecision*j)))+(0.5 *cos(minY+(yPrecision*k)));

                }else if(menuSelection==4){

                    val[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(xPrecision*j)))+(minX+(xPrecision*j)) * cos(3 * (minY+(yPrecision*k))); 

                }       

            //Increment Array Index
            i++;
    }//End of j loop



    //Increment y-values
    if(k<graduationVal){

        k++;
    }

 }//End of While
return val;
}

void displayValues(double result[],int result_size,int numOfGraduations){

  int displaySelection=0;
  cerr<<"(0) Bitmap or (1) Values?";
  cin>>displaySelection;

  int k=0;
  int i=0;


  while(i< result_size){


    for(int j=0;j<numOfGraduations;j++){

       if(displaySelection==1){
        cout<<result[i]<<" ";
       }else{

        cout<<((result[i] > 0 )?"O":"X");

       }

        i++;
    }   

    cout<<"\n";

  }

}


int main(){

 int menuChoice=-1;
 int displaychoice=0;

 double distanceFromMinMaxX=4+6;
 double distanceFromMinMaxY=12+5;

 int graduations=0;

double precisionX;
double precisionY;

 double pctIncrease;

   while(menuChoice!=0){

          cerr<<"Select your function\n";
          cerr<<"1. sin(x)cos(y)\n";
          cerr<<"2. sin(x)+cos^2(x)-x/y\n";
          cerr<<"3. 1/2 sin(x) + 1/2 cos(y)\n";
          cerr<<"4. 1/2 sin(x) + xcos(3y)\n";
          cerr<<"0. Quit\n";
          cin>>menuChoice;

          if(menuChoice == 0){

            return 0;
          }

          cerr<<"Number of graduations per axis: ";
          cin>>graduations;

          pctIncrease=1/(double)(graduations - 1);
          int values_size=graduations * graduations;

          double values[values_size];


          /*int yValues[graduationVal];*/

          precisionX=distanceFromMinMaxX/graduations;
          precisionY=distanceFromMinMaxY/graduations;

          /*cout << "# of graduations: " << graduations << endl;
          cout << "Precision: "<< endl;
          cout << "x: " << precisionX << endl;
          cout << "y: " << precisionY << endl;*/

          calculateValues(values,values_size,graduations,precisionX,precisionY,menuChoice);
          displayValues(values,values_size,graduations);




   }

}
```

Edit:I am using gcc

Comment: "I still am not getting desired output." it will be helpful to describe what is the  output you desire.

Comment: Hi.I have added an image for the output I am trying to get but it's not working.

Comment: The image you linked doesn't tell me a thing. Use words.

Comment: Oh, you want an xy plot. Why didn't you say so? Your question would have been simpler: "I'm computing some Y values for X-es I compute somehow, I'm having difficulties in organizing the result as an ASCII X-Y plot." Suggestion: separate the code implemented for computation of your values from the code to handle the display. The code will become clearer an more manageable - currently the `displayValues` does the something indescribable.

Comment: Ok! I have seperated the code but I am getting error when I am trying to store the array returned from calculateValues function to values array.

Comment: Since you pass the `values` as an argument to be filled in by calculate value, you don;t need to assign it again with the return of `calculateValues`. Just `calculateValues(values,values_size,graduations,precisionX,precisionY,menuChoice);` followed by `calculateValues(values,values_size,graduations,precisionX,precisionY,menuChoice);` would be sufficient.

Comment: However, the way you declare ``double values[values_size];` is not Ok, as it depends by the user input: the compiler has no idea (at compilation time), how much space to reserve to the variables. You need to dynamically allocate the memory at runtime. Using either `new double[<size>]` or `malloc` (whatever you teacher chose to tell you) and free the memory before you exit from the block you allocated them in (in this case the `while` block). Freeing the memory - is allocated with `new` use `delete[]` if allocated with `malloc` use `free`.

Comment: Done.But I am still not getting the desired output!

Comment: "But I am still not getting the desired output!" May be so. Time for you now to use the debugger and see why you are getting unexpected results. Instead of trigonometric funcs, use some simpler ones, like a simple line or a parabola, things that you can calculate easily outside you program. Once you fix you bugs,  you will be commenting or deleting the code for those functions anyway.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: Got the output!!Appearently,I had function#2 as wrong.Now that I fixed it,I got the answer!!Thank you @AdrianColomitchi for a big help!

Comment: Congratulations. A honest work, and all yours. Doesn't it feel good?

Comment: Yes it does.I just wanted to understand why the code was broken!Really feels good to know it works now!

Comment: (in regards with the debugger: when you have time, get yourself used with [`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) - is the debugger of choice if you compile with gcc)

Comment: Oh ok! I will look into it.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This produces output similar to the screencap you linked (where the user chose option 2).  The `TextPlot2d` function takes a lambda or functor which calculates the desired function, as well as two `PlotRange` structs for specifying how the x and y axes should be scaled.  I also used different output characters because I had a hard time distinguishing 'X' vs. 'O'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct PlotRange {
    double begin, end, count;
    double get_step() const { return (end - begin) / count; }
};

template <typename F>
void TextPlot2d(F func, PlotRange range_x, PlotRange range_y) {
    const auto step_x = range_x.get_step();
    const auto step_y = range_y.get_step();
    // multiply steps by iterated integer
    // to avoid accumulation of error in x and y
    for(int j = 0;; ++j) {
        auto y = range_y.begin + step_y * j;
        if(y >= range_y.end) break;
        for(int i = 0;; ++i) {
            auto x = range_x.begin + step_x * i;
            if(x >= range_x.end) break;
            auto z = func(x, y);
            if(z != z) { std::cout << '?'; } // NaN outputs a '?'
            else       { std::cout << (z < 0 ? '#':'o'); }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    TextPlot2d(
        [](double x, double y){ return std::sin(x) + std::cos(y/2)*std::cos(y/2) - x/y; },
        {-4.0, 6.0, 40.0},
        {-12.0, 5.0, 40.0}
    );
}
```

Tada!

```
ooooooo######ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooo#######ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooo#########oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooo###########ooooooooooooooooo######oo
ooo#############ooooooooooooooo#######oo
ooo#############ooooooooooooooo########o
oo##############ooooooooooooooo########o
ooo#############ooooooooooooooo########o
ooo#############oooooooooooooooo######oo
oooo###########oooooooooooooooooo####ooo
ooooo#########oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooo#########oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooo#######ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooo######ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooo#######ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooo#######ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooo#########oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooo############ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oo#############ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
################oooooooooooooooooooooooo
################oooooooooooooooooooooooo
################oooooooooooooooooooooooo
################oooooooooooooooooooooooo
################oooooooooooooooooooooooo
###############ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
###############ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
###############ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
###############ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
################oooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooooooooooooooo######################
oooooooooooooooooooooo##################
oooooooooooooooooooooooo################
ooooooooooooooooooooooooo###############
ooooooooooo###ooooooooooo###############
ooooooooo#######ooooooooo###############
oooooooo########oooooooooo##############
ooooooo#########oooooooooo##############
ooooooo#########ooooooooooo#############
ooooooo########oooooooooooo#############
oooooooo######oooooooooooooo############
```

Comment: We just learned about struct and since this is old assignment,I can't use struct

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the output!!Appearantly function#2 was wrong and that's why I wasn't getting correct answer.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    double minX=-4;
    double maxX=6;
    double minY=-12;
    double maxY=5;


    void calculateValues(double val[],int val_size,int graduationVal,double xPrecision,double yPrecision,int menuSelection){

      /*int displaySelection=0;
      cerr<<"(0) Bitmap or (1) Values?";
      cin>>displaySelection;*/

      //double val[];
      int k=0;
      int i=0;

      //Add Values into array until result-1 values
      while(i < val_size){


        for(int j=0; j<graduationVal;j++){
                    if(menuSelection==1){
                        val[i]=sin(minX+(xPrecision*j))*cos(minY+(yPrecision*k));

                    }else if(menuSelection==2){
                        val[i]=sin(minX+(xPrecision*j))+pow(cos((minY+(yPrecision*k))/2),2)-(minX+(xPrecision*j))/(minY+(yPrecision*k));

                    }else if(menuSelection==3){

                        val[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(xPrecision*j)))+(0.5 *cos(minY+(yPrecision*k)));

                    }else if(menuSelection==4){

                        val[i]=(0.5 * sin(minX+(xPrecision*j)))+(minX+(xPrecision*j)) * cos(3 * (minY+(yPrecision*k))); 

                    }       

                //Go to next value in array
                i++;
        }//End of j loop



        //Increment y-values
        if(k<graduationVal){

            k++;
        }

     }//End of While
      }

    void displayValues(double result[],int result_size,int numOfGraduations){

      int displaySelection=0;
      cerr<<"(0) Bitmap or (1) Values?";
      cin>>displaySelection;

      int k=0;
      int i=0;


      while(i< result_size){


        for(int j=0;j<numOfGraduations;j++){

           if(displaySelection==1){
            cout<<result[i]<<" ";
           }else{

            cout<<((result[i] > 0 )?"O":"#");

           }

            i++;
        }   

        cout<<"\n";

      }

    }


    int main(){

     int menuChoice=-1;
     int displaychoice=0;

     double distanceFromMinMaxX=maxX-minX;
     double distanceFromMinMaxY=maxY-minY;

     int graduations=0;

    double precisionX;
    double precisionY;

     double pctIncrease;

       while(menuChoice!=0){

              cerr<<"Select your function\n";
              cerr<<"1. sin(x)cos(y)\n";
              cerr<<"2. sin(x)+cos^2(y/2)-x/y\n";
              cerr<<"3. 1/2 sin(x) + 1/2 cos(y)\n";
              cerr<<"4. 1/2 sin(x) + xcos(3y)\n";
              cerr<<"0. Quit\n";
              cin>>menuChoice;

              if(menuChoice == 0){

                return 0;
              }

              cerr<<"Number of graduations per axis: ";
              cin>>graduations;

              //pctIncrease=1/(double)(graduations - 1);
              int values_size=graduations * graduations;

              double values[values_size];


              /*int yValues[graduationVal];*/

              precisionX=(distanceFromMinMaxX)/graduations;
              precisionY=(distanceFromMinMaxY)/graduations;

              /*cout << "# of graduations: " << graduations << endl;
              cout << "Precision: "<< endl;
              cout << "x: " << precisionX << endl;
              cout << "y: " << precisionY << endl;*/

              calculateValues(values,values_size,graduations,precisionX,precisionY,menuChoice);
              displayValues(values,values_size,graduations);




       }

    }
```